# generating signed bundle requires gradle version 3.2.0 or more

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

This message  **generating signed  bundle requires gradle version 3.2.0 or more**  appears whenever I try to create a signed apk

I have updated gradle version to higher than 3.2.0 but **still this error appearing on the screen**

[image]

[image]

[image]

DO YOU HAVE ANY SOLUTION FOR IT. HOW CAN I SOLVE THIS

Comment: I'm getting the same error, despite having Gradle version 6.5 installed. Did you ever find a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late. But are you using intelliJ. If so do that in android studio instead